# How declaring and add data in new object correctly

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
struct Calculators
{
    var calculators: [Calculator]?
    var activeCalculator: Int = -1
    var activeSummary: Bool = false
    var activeProfits: Bool = false

    public func getCalculators()-> [Calculator]
    {
        return calculators!
    }
}    

struct Calculator
{
    var priceSum: Float = 0
    var weightSum: Float = 0
    var pricePerMix: Float = 0

    var pricePerPortion: Decimal?
    var portionDivider: Float?
    var nettoPortionCost: Float?
    var profitPerPortion: Float?
    var pricePerKgAfterPrepare: Float?
    var weightPerPortionInGrams: Float? 

    var products : [CountedProduct]?

    init() {
        createTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    }
}

struct CountedProduct
{
    var productCode: String
    var productCountable: Bool 
    var pricePerKg: Decimal?
    var weightYieldInPercent: Decimal?
    var pieceWeight: Decimal? 
} 

var countedProduct = CountedProduct(productCode: produkt.code!, productCountable: productCountable, pricePerKg: pricePerKg, weightYieldInPercent: weightYieldInPercent, pieceWeight: pieceWeight)

var activeCalculators = Calculators()
var calculatorToAdd = Calculator()
calculatorToAdd.priceSum = 0 
calculatorToAdd.weightSum = 0 //?
calculatorToAdd.pricePerMix = Float(countedProduct.weightAfterPrepareKg as! NSNumber)
calculatorToAdd.pricePerPortion = (countedProduct.costOfTheMixturePerPortion as! NSNumber).decimalValue
calculatorToAdd.portionDivider = 0 //?
calculatorToAdd.nettoPortionCost = Float(countedProduct.costOfTheMixturePerPortion as! NSNumber)
calculatorToAdd.profitPerPortion = Float(countedProduct.overheadOnServing as! NSNumber)
calculatorToAdd.pricePerKgAfterPrepare = Float(countedProduct.pricePerKgAfterPrepare as! NSNumber)
calculatorToAdd.weightPerPortionInGrams = Float(countedProduct.weightAfterPrepareKg as! NSNumber)
calculatorToAdd.products?.append(countedProduct)
calculatorToAdd.products?.append(countedProduct)
```

I can not change the form of these class.
How to correctly initialize a Calculators object?
I have data in produkt.

Is this code correct?

I would like to create a calculator object and insert it into Calculators.
The class code can not be changed.

Comment: [This](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) is good documentation with many examples on initialization of classes and structs, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can add to the code at the end

```
activeCalculators.calculators = []
activeCalculators.calculators.append(calculatorToAdd)
```